# openpyxl and excel macros

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, vba, openpyxl

I am on winodws 10, Python 3.7.

When i work with openpyxl and .xlsm files, once my xlsm is edited/saved through openpyxl, all buttons assigned to macros disappear (the macros are still there). Here is my test code:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename='my_file.xlsm', keep_vba=True)
ws = wb["sheet1"]
c = ws.cell(row = 1, column = 1)
c.value = "test"
wb.save('my_file.xlsm')
```

Any opinions on why the buttons disappear?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps is related to https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/1027/vba-turned-into-images

Comment: Nobody has yet done the work to support these controls.

Comment: Thanks both for your input.

Answer (score 0):

When you save the file. It basically saves as a new file instead of replacing the old one.
Try saving with a different name and then you can see the difference.